# Subscription to a subject not triggering

Tags: angular

I am struggling to make one subscription works without any result.

The idea is to have a simple RoutingService that subscribe to an AuthService as I want the routing/navigation to happen outside the AuthService. When there are changes in the AuthService (login/logout), I want to send an event to the RoutingService and according to the result navigate to a component or not.

Before adding the code, I've been doing some research on other posts. Here is some answer to the questions you have in mind right now:

- All my Services are declared only once in my root module, therefore they are a singleton. I don't have any other Service/Module with the provider's element
- I tried to use Subject, ReplaySubject, and BheaviourSubject, same result...

Find the code below:

**AuthService class**

```
@Injectable() export class AuthService implements OnInit {

    private authorized = false;
    private googleResponse: GoogleUser;
    authorizationChanges: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
    authorizationChangesObservable;

    constructor(private router: Router, private googleAuth: GoogleAuthService, private ngZone: NgZone) {
        this.authorizationChanges = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.authorized);
        this.authorizationChangesObservable = this.authorizationChanges.asObservable();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // also tried to initialize the subject and observable here, same result   }

      //method triggered after a successful signIn   
    private signInSuccessHandler(res: GoogleUser) {
        this.googleResponse = res;
        if (this.validateAccountDomain()) {
            this.authorized = res.isSignedIn();
        }
        console.log('triggering authorizationChanges event');  //<-- I can see this log message in the console
        // So far this is not working
        this.authorizationChanges.next(this.authorized);
    }
}
```

**RoutingService**

```
@Injectable()
export class RoutingService implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    authorizationUpdates: Subscription;
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { //tried to subscribe in the constructor, same result
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.authorizationUpdates = this.authService.authorizationChangesObservable.subscribe((authorized) => {
            console.log(authorized); // <--- I can not see in the console
            this.router.navigate(['assessment'])
        })

     // doesn't work
     // this.authService.authorizationChanges.subscribe(
     //   (authorized) => { console.log('second try')})
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.authorizationUpdates.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: remove `this.authorizationChangesObservable` or use it, and tell us how it goes

Comment: sorry, forgot to clean a little bit the code, used both cases, same result. The console does not log and the navigate doesn't trigger. Let me add it to the post

Comment: And does it work when your route directly from the auth service ?

Comment: yes. if I route directly from the signInSuccessHandler method,  is working as expected but I don't want to mix the routing with the AuthService

Comment: Well, you already have a "native" service provided by angular. Here, you're just adding one step to it. I understand you want to separate concerns, but sometimes it's just not needed !

Comment: Indeed, it could be a necessary or not. Nevertheless, I would like to know why this is not working as I could encounter the same situation any other time

Comment: Well I already faced this issue and never resolved it (I used an auth service, same as you, and I implemented route guards in it, the functions would not redirect to login page), so I found some workarounds instead. Sorry I can't be of any help !

Comment: Hi, I would be surprised if the lifecycle hooks are working for services. They are only working for Components etc. Can you try to subscribe to the Subject in the constructor?!

Comment: tried to Subscribe in both init / constructor for both services, no results. If the hooks are not working for services, how to communicate changes?  Just by calling any method of the service being call ?

Comment: Can you share your link to StackBlitz link. would help to see further

Answer (score 1):

[Lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html), like `OnInit()` work with Directives and Components. They do not work with other types, like a service in your case.

OnInit has to do with binding. You use it when you want to wait for input values to be resolved, as they are not available in the constructor. Constructor can be called multiple times. For example, when you change route and load different components they get "constructed" and destroyed each time

You can move the ngOnInit logic to the constructor for Injectable classes.

Comment: That's a really useful info that I was not aware of, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, moving the init code to the constructor block does not solve the problem